# Including a GMail sidebar gadget within an installable Google Marketplace listing

Tags: gmail, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, igoogle

I would like to build an application that I can list on the Google Apps Marketplace so that organization administrators can install it with one-click.

The application interacts with Google through a sidebar in Gmail.  I've been able to start testing this with the "Add Gadget by URL" GMail Labs feature, but now I would like to package it in an application that the admins can roll out to all their users at the same time.

[Google's documentation for application manifests](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/manifest) mentions how to add contextual gadgets, but not sidebar gadgets.  Does anyone have experience adding a sidebar gadget within an application manifest?

**Example of a sidebar that I'd like to embed:**

```
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs height="400" title="Mike's First Sidebar!">
    <Require feature="views"/>
    <Require feature="dynamic-height"/>
    <Require feature="settitle"/>
  </ModulePrefs>
  <Content type="html" view="home">
    <![CDATA[
      <h2>Todo:</h2>
          <ul>
             <li>Create a sidebar gadget</li>
             <li>Add it to an application</li>
             <li>List the application on the marketplace</li>
          </ul>
    ]]>
  </Content>
</Module>
```

Comment: Have you tried to include your sidebar gadget in the same way as contextual gadgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of documentation is simply because that isn't a supported feature.